# GeoCoordinateWatcher Permission when attached to a Desktop running Vista

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I am creating a basic WindowsPhone7 app that uses the GeoCoordinateWatcher class - I based my app on the example found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DEVICE.LOCATION.GEOCOORDINATEWATCHER%29&rd=true).  I notice that when I keep the phone attached to my Vista machine for debugging, the Permission property returns false.  The MSDN page has this blurb:

*On Windows 7 Starter Edition, the only supported location provider is the Default Location Provider in Control Panel, and an add-in must be installed to specify latitude and longitude.*

How can I enable my Vista machine to prove Lat and long?  Also - why is the desktop providing the coordinates and not the Win Phone?

Answer (score 0):

Right below the blurb you reference is this note:

> **Note**   In versions of Windows prior to Windows 7, the following conditions apply:
>
> All System.Device.Location objects that have constructors can be created, but the Status >property will always have the value Disabled.
>
> The location indicated by the Location property of Position will always be Unknown.
>
> No location events will be raised.

I don't think you'll be able to get Vista to provide Lat/Long.

As to why your phone isn't providing the coordinates, make sure you are using

```
GeoCoordinateAccuracy.High
```

That will ensure you're using the phone GPS.

Comment: The phone is still not provding coordinates - even after waiting a couple of minutes.  Also interstingly, I hooked into the status_changed event and the status goes from Initializing and then to disabled.  I set the UserIdeledDectionMode to Disabled and it is still disabling with no coordinates.  If this is by design, it makes it really hard to debug...

Comment: Can the phone get a GPS signal from where you are? (Do other location-based apps work and are they GPS-accurate or just triangulation accurate?) GeoCoordinateAccuracy.High won't work if you can't get a GPS signal.

Comment: I read the Data from the Location Service for Windows Phone article from MSDN.  In the code, if the status is disabled and the GeoPositionPermission is denied, then the location is disabled on the device.  However, on my phone (HTC Trophy), the Location is turned on.  <sigh />

Comment: Do you have a Windows 7 machine you can test on?

Comment: I don't know how to check for a GPS specific singal on the phone - other location based apps work.  I'll monkey around with the settings....

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from APP HUB [Here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/86652/520805.aspx#520805%20/%22Here%22).  I needed the ID_CAP_LOCATION tag in my manifest